# Random animation on Simple Image Slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I want to apply a random animation on my slideshow image.  First, I tried adding an animation such as scale but it didn't work as I wanted it to.

Things I want to fix:

1. Smoothness on fadein
2. Random animation (can be anything at this point, I just want to see how it's done)

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jzhang172/e7cLtsg9/1/

```js
$(function() {
  $('img').hide();

  function anim() {
    $("#wrap img").first().appendTo('#wrap').fadeOut(3500).addClass('transition').addClass('scaleme');
    $("#wrap img").first().fadeIn(3500).removeClass('scaleme');
    setTimeout(anim, 3700);
  }
  anim();
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: black;
}
#wrap img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.transition {
  transition: 10s;
}
.scaleme {
  transition: 10s;
  transform: scale(1.3);
}
.box {
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <div id="wrap">
    <img src="http://elegantthemes.com/preview/InStyle/wp-content/uploads/2008/11/s-1.jpg" />
    <img src="http://elegantthemes.com/preview/InStyle/wp-content/uploads/2008/11/s-5.jpg" />
    <img src="http://elegantthemes.com/preview/InStyle/wp-content/uploads/2008/11/s-3.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Improved that smoothness, you could animate right if you wanted to.

Edit: Forgot link: http://jsfiddle.net/e7cLtsg9/2/

Comment: Very nice, this helped me, still trying to figure out how to do a random animation

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late response, I've been busy, this definitely helped, I just wanted to give it best answer after I tried it.

Comment: Oh sorry, that's fine @Snorlax. I wasn't sure because it was a deviation from your original approach :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample using CSS animations and jQuery (for achieving the randomness of animations). If you don't wish to use CSS animations and want to  stick to transitions + jQuery effects (like `fadeIn`), you can still adapt this code to support it because the base idea will still remain the same. I am not too comfortable with jQuery effects and have hence stuck to using CSS animations.

Below is an overview of how it is being done (refer inline comments for more details):

- Inside a wrapper there are a group of images that are part of the slide-show (like in your demo).
- Using CSS `@keyframes`, a list of animations (one of which would be used randomly) is created in addition to the default fade-in-out animation. This list is also maintained in an array variable (in JS for picking up a random one from the list).
- On load, the default fade-in-out animation and one random animation is added to the 1st element.
- An `animationend` event handler is added to all of the images. This event handler will be triggered when the animation on an element ends. When this is triggered, animation on the current element is removed and the default fade-in-out + a random animation is added to the next element.
- The animations are added using inline styles because if we add multiple CSS classes each with one different animation, then the animation in the latest class will override the others (that is, they will not happen together).
- A loop effect is achieved by checking if the current element has any other `img` sibling elements. If there are none, the animation is added back to the 1st element.

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  $img = $('img'); // the images
  var anim = ['zoom', 'shrink', 'move-down-up', 'move-right-left']; // the list of random animations
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1; // random number
  
  $img.each(function() { // attach event handler for each image
    
    $(this).on('animationend', function(e) { // when animation on one image has ended
      
      if (e.originalEvent.animationName == 'fade-in-out') { // check the animation's name
        rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1; // get a random number
        $(this).css('animation-name', 'none'); // remove animation on current element
        if ($(this).next('img').length > 0) // if there is a next sibling
          $(this).next('img').css('animation-name', 'fade-in-out, ' + anim[rand - 1]); // add animation on next sibling
        else
          $img.eq(0).css('animation-name', 'fade-in-out, ' + anim[rand - 1]); // else add animation on first image (loop)
      }
    });
  });
  $img.eq(0).css('animation-name', 'fade-in-out, ' + anim[rand - 1]); //add animation to 1st element on load
})
```

```css
#wrapper {
  height: 250px;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
}
img {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 10px;
  opacity: 0;
  transform-origin: left top; /* to be on the safe side */
  animation-duration: 3s; /* increase only if you want duration to be longer */
  animation-fill-mode: backwards; /* fill mode - better to not change */
  animation-iteration-count: 1; /* no. of iterations - don't change */
  animation-timing-function: ease; /* better to leave as-is but can be changed */
}
@keyframes fade-in-out {
  0%, 100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  33.33%, 66.66% { /* duration is 3s, so fade-in at 1s, stay till 2s, fade-out from 2s */
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes zoom {
  0%, 100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.5);
  }
}
@keyframes shrink {
  0%, 100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(.5);
  }
}
@keyframes move-down-up {
  0%, 100% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(50px);
  }
}
@keyframes move-right-left {
  0%, 100% {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(50px);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/200/000000/ffffff" />
  <img src="https://placehold.it/200/ff0000/ffffff" />
  <img src="https://placehold.it/200/00ff00/ffffff" />
  <img src="https://placehold.it/200/0000ff/ffffff" />
</div>
```